# Search and Index not working after converting from Word 2016 to CHM

Tags: ms-word, docx, chm

I have converted a 400 page Word 2016 .docx document to .chm using chmProcessor v1.7.3. The contents and formatting are surprisingly good, but when I load the .chm file:

1. The Search tab does not work at all (it just displays the first
   Heading in the Contents and nothing else).
2. The Index is much the same as the Contents

How do I get this to work properly? Or is there a better converter?

Running on Win 10 Pro, 64bit, Word 2016

Answer (score 2):

Never used chmProcessor before (because using other tools) but surprisingly seems to be a good one for converting Word documents in a simple way. But, you need to do something more.

The short story - you need to edit e.g. the **Cut header level** as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Without having tried this in deep and only by a quick use of chmProcessor:

On a preference level of zero all Word contents goes to one HTML topic. So, when you perform a search only this one HTML file has a match. But inside all the keywords matched are highlighted (if activated). After searching scroll down in your topic pane on the right to see what I mean.

You'll need a minimum of e.g. headline level 1, headline level 2, etc. in your Word document (structured topics and subtopics). First try to set **Cut Header level** to 2. This means you'll get some more HTML files.

By using the **Search** tab of your CHM file now you'll get some more detailed results.

Indexing seems to be derived here from the Word topic headlines. Good structured documents with e.g. a one-word headline have a good Index but long headlines don't give back an index in a single keyword way.

You'll need to go deep into help authoring and compiling CHM's with index. This has a learn curve.

Try to use **Generate help project** (see screenshot) for your needs to see all the topics and the index file e.g. **Index-generated.hhk**.

Comment: This sounded very promising, except when I put non zero values in it just hung. Nothing appeared in the Log or Errors tab. I tried several times, with shorter word documents too. Odd since it worked with the full document with those entries all left at zero!

Comment: I tried with a 60 pages document and Nummern headlines with three levels. Search is Ok for me but index needs much work as mentioned above. Have you tried to converter to a Help project? How man HTML files are converter as a result?

Comment: thanks, but it seems that Malwarebytes was causing it to hang (which I found looking for a solution to Word 2016 hanging when doing Save As PDF). And now the Help search is working (although Save As PDF still isn't working)! Thank you! :) :)

Comment: BTW - you say you don't use chmProcessor, is there a better application for converting .docx to .chm?

Comment: I'm using ZenHelp sometimes. This is old stuff no longer supported and I have a 10 years old licence (Beta Tester). This is an addin for Microsoft Word. The index is derived from Word index keywords. But, chmProcessor seems to be better for me now, because HTML files and all files are generated. I have many years of experience using (and selling) a tool named FAR HTML. So, I'm using this tool in my workflow to edit the foobar.hhk file. and compile out of the box. Many other (expensive) tools are available. As said, creating content and index files is time consuming.

Comment: @drb01 - when this answer was helpful please check as answered.