# Generate .hhk file From Word Document

Tags: ms-word, chm, html-help-workshop

I am trying to convert MS Word file to chm file. I have a well organized word document. But,I could not figure out how to word saved as a html file to chm file. I know I can add html file to created project but there are some issue such that I could not solve how to convert ms word table of content file to index file in html help workshop program. I would be very happy If someone provide some example about conversion of word documents.(I am trying to achieve this thorough HTML Help Workshop program)

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a Word document to CHM format is difficult without special (often expensive) tools and has a learning curve.

You should think about whether the PDF format is not sufficient. But the CHM format - integrated in the Windows operating system - has of course some popular functions.

I recommend to read through [Search and Index not working after converting from Word 2016 to CHM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036208/search-and-index-not-working-after-converting-from-word-2016-to-chm).

As I mentioned in my answer I never used chmProcessor before (because using other tools) but surprisingly seems to be a good one for converting Word documents in a simple way.

Please try chmProcessor for your needs. You may want to ask a new question here on SO later.

Edit:

Maybe you have additional interest in the following CodeProject article:

[How to Easily Write a User's Guide for Your Application using Different File Extensions](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1245830/How-to-easily-write-a-users-guide-for-your-applica)